Smallest ${\mathbf B}$-function $f:\omega\to( \omega\setminus\{0\})$
Motivation. Every hypergraph $(\omega, E)$ where $E$ is countable and consists of infinite sets has property $\newcommand{\B}{\mathbf{B}}\B$. On the other hand, if the members of $E$ are allowed to be finite, it is easy to construct hypergraphs $(\omega,E)$ without property $\B$. I am interested in settings with finite edges where $\B$ holds. Let's make this precise.
Formalization. A hypergraph $H=(V,E)$ is said to have property $\B$ if there is $B\subseteq V$ such that $$e\cap B\neq\emptyset\neq e\setminus B$$ for all $e\in E$ with $|e|>1$.
A $\B$-function is a map $f:\omega\to (\omega\setminus \{0\})$ such that

whenever $E$ is a countable collection of finite subsets of $\omega$ and $\varphi:\omega\to E$ is a bijection with $$|\varphi(n)|=f(n)$$ for all $n\in\omega$, the hypergraph $(\omega, E)$ has property $\B$.

Question. In the comments below, Andreas Blass finds a $\B$-function. Is there a $\B$-function $f_0:\omega\to(\omega\setminus\{0\})$ such that for every $\B$-function $f$ we have $f_0(n)\leq f(n)$ for all $n\in\omega$?

Well, $f(n)=2n+2$ seems to work for the same reason as in te case of infinite hyperedges. Just go through the hyperedges one at a time, choosing two new elements from each --- one to go into $B$ and one to stay outside $B$. $2n+2$ ensures that, when you get to hyperedge $\varphi(n)$, you can choose two new (i.e., not previously chosen) elements, since the $n$ prior steps chose only $2n$ elements.

Ok thanks I overlooked this. Is there a smallest B-function? Will rephrase question

I don't know about a smallest $f$, but my previous $f$  can be improved to $\max(n+1,2)$ with no added work. When you get to $\varphi(n)$, check which of its elements were chosen previously. If some went into $B$ and some out, then you don't need to do anything for $\varphi(n)$. If some went in and none out (or vice versa), then there are at most $n$ of them, so there's at least one unchosen one, and you only need to choose one. And if none have been previously chosen, then you need two and you have at least two.

Note that my constructions are "online" in the sense that, when working on $\varphi(n)$, you use information only about the sets $\varphi(k)$ for $k\leq n$. I don't see a way to do better than $\max(n+1,2)$ online, but I have no good idea about what might be possible by looking ahhead, to larger $k$.

Thank you to both Andreas and bof. Can you post your comment as an answer, bof?

The question is really about finite hypergraphs, seeing as an infinite hypergraph (with finite edges) is $2$-colorable (i.e., has property B) iff every finite subhypergraph is $2$-colorable. In effect you are asking about which finite multisets of integers $\ge2$ can be realized as the multiset of edge-sizes of a hypergraph which does not have property B. This is a well-considered question, at least for uniform multisets; see Karl Grill and Daniel Linzmayer, Improved lower bounds for property B (arxiv).
Since a rearrangement of a B-function is a B-function, you probably want to restrict your question to nondecreasing B-functions. Even with this restriction there is no smallest B-function, in view of the following.
The sequence $f=(3,3,3,3,3,6,7,8,9,\dots)$ is a B-function, in view of the fact that $m(3)\gt5$ where $m(n)$ is the minimum number of edges in an $n$-uniform hypergraph which does not have property B. (In fact $m(3)=7$; the smallest $3$-uniform hypergraph without property B is the Fano plane.) The sequence $g=(2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,\dots)$ is also a B-function. However, the sequence $\min(f,g)=(2,2,3,3,3,6,7,8,9,\dots)$ is not a B-function, since the hypergraph with edges $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,3\}$, $\{2,3,4\}$, $\{2,3,5\}$, $\{1,4,5\}$ does not have property B.
